# nginx is not sending requests to php-fpm if URI contains "dashboard" but it does for all other URIs

Tags: nginx, php

I'm rolling my own MVC framework and this is driving me crazy.  I have all URLs that dont resolve to actual files redirect to `/index.php?$args`.  Within the framework I interrogate the REQUEST_URI to extract the context and parameters of the request.  I stole this configuration snippet from the [nginx wiki "Front Controller Pattern"](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls) .

Examples:

1. `example.com/dashboard`
2. `example.com/user/456`
3. `example.com/devices`
4. `example.com/blog/789`

All of the above should send to php-fpm a request for index.php.  My problem is that #1 does not, yet #2, #3, and #4 work as expected.

In the #1 case, nginx (I think) is not sending to php-fpm but is instead returning the contents of index.php and I end up with a save file dialog for a file called "dashboard" and within the file is my index.php source code.

Here is my relevant nginx configuration:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include php_conf;
}


location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
}
```

My php_conf is standard stuff:

```
# With php5-fpm:
fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index   index.php;
fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
fastcgi_ignore_client_abort     off;

fastcgi_param   DB_HOST        [redacted];
fastcgi_param   DB_USER        [redacted];
fastcgi_param   DB_NAME        [redacted];
fastcgi_param   DB_PASS        [redacted];

fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

include         fastcgi_params;
```

And fastcgi_params is this:

```
fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING            $query_string;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD          $request_method;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE            $content_type;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH          $content_length;

fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME         $request_filename;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME             $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI             $request_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI            $document_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT           $document_root;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL         $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param   GATEWAY_INTERFACE       CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_SOFTWARE         nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR             $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param   REMOTE_PORT             $remote_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR             $server_addr;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT             $server_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME             $server_name;

fastcgi_param   HTTPS                   $https;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param   REDIRECT_STATUS         200;
```

Anyone have an idea why the `/devices` URI works but `/dashboard` does not?

What is the nginx best practice for transforming user and SEO friendly URLs such as the above format to calls to index.php?

I'm quite certain there is no file called `/dashboard` on the filesystem and it certainly doesn't contain the contents of my index.php file.

Also an interesting additional symptom:  Cases 2,3,4 result in HTTP 200 log entries in the access.log, but in the case #1, nothing in the access or error logs for nginx even though the server sends out the source contents of index.php.

I'm baffled.

Answer (score 0):

I never figured out the root cause, but I'm starting to suspect that nginx on vagrant is not 100% reliable.  I rebuilt the vagrant server and the above configuration does work.

So when in doubt:  "vagrant destroy; vagrant up"